# Will booting windows 10 from a USB drive affect grub in any way?

Tags: windows

I use Ubuntu. But I urgently need a windows 10 OS for a test. I was wondering whether it is possible to boot into windows 10 from USB drive, to avoid deletion of grub. I'm in lockdown at the moment, and can't access any electronics stores to purchase a hard drive for backup. All I have at the moment is a USB stick.

Answer (score 1):

Just booting into Windows 10 will not affect your existing boot loader in any way.

Comment: but installing it wil?

Comment: Installing will, correct. Not only that the Windows 10 installer will overwrite EFI variables in your BIOS.